# Is there a design for C# that removes the need for dynamic?

Tags: c#, design, generics, dynamic

I have a web service that implements Repository Pattern and I was wondering if there is a design in C# that can remove the need for 'dynamic' when injecting it in my method.

```
public interface IRepositoryPlan : IRepository<PlanDetail>
{
    // methods...
}

public interface IRepositoryFlan : IRepository<FlanDetail>
{
    // methods...
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IList<T> Retrieve();
}
```

I am using NancyFx as my web service framework.

```
public class ClassModule : NancyModule
{
    public ClassModule(IRepositoryPlan repoPlan, IRepositoryFlan repoFlan)
    {
        Get["/RetrievePlan"] = _ =>
        {
            RetrieveMethod(repoPlan);
        }

        Get["/RetrieveFlan"] = _ =>
        {
            RetrieveMethod(repoFlan);
        }
    }

    RetrieveMethod(dynamic repoPFlan)
    {
          dynamic detail = repoPFlan.Retrieve();
    }
}
```

Is there a design for removing 'dynamic' in my RetrieveMethod? I know I can just use method overloading here and have two RetrieveMethods but what can I do if I have multiple repositories that I need to retrieve?

Comment: What is RetrieveMethod doing with the detail? That is the crucial part.

Comment: You can probably make the RetrieveMethod generic so that it takes a `IRepository<T>` parameter?

Comment: @Euphoric We can just assume that Im feeding that data into a view of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class ClassModule : NancyModule
{
    public ClassModule(IRepositoryPlan repoPlan, IRepositoryFlan repoFlan)
    {
        Get["/RetrievePlan"] = _ =>
        {
            RetrieveMethod(repoPlan);
        }

        Get["/RetrieveFlan"] = _ =>
        {
            RetrieveMethod(repoFlan);
        }
    }

    RetrieveMethod<T>(IRepository<T> repo)
    {
        // don't care about type of detail, as View will use reflection to access the properties
        dynamic detail = repo.Retrieve();
    }
}
```

Comment: `IRepository<T>.Retrieve` returns `IList<T>` you don't need the dynamic

Comment: @Caleth Yes, you can specify IList<T> instead of dynamic. But that won't give you much information as T won't be much more than object in this place. And it's type is irrelevant if it is passed as dynamic into View.